# How can I update the rows that are existed before the insert using Trigger ( SQL Server )?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm looking for a method to update old rows before an insert or update using a Trigger ,

For example , I have this table

```
ID      PersonID      Name     Status
1        001          Alex      False        
2        002          Mark      True
```

What I need exactly is that when I insert in this table a new row (3,003,Jane,True) , the column status should be affected to False ( all old rows ) only the new row will have `True`

So the expected result when applying the trigger will be like this :

```
ID      PersonID      Name     Status
1        001          Alex      False        
2        002          Mark      False
3        003          Jane      True
```

How can I do this?

What I have tried:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[dbo.TR_SetStatus] ON [dbo].[Person]
after INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS
DECLARE @CursorTestID INT = 1;
DECLARE @RowCnt BIGINT = 0;
BEGIN
DECLARE @count INT;
    
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM Person;
 
WHILE @CursorTestID <= @RowCnt
BEGIN
update Person set status=0 
SET @CursorTestID = @CursorTestID + 1 

END

END
```

I have two questions:

- How can I update the rows that are existed before the insert using Trigger ( SQL Server )?
- How can I pass a parameter to a trigger? (as an example PersonID)

Comment: In an insert trigger, all (do NOT assume a single row was inserted) of the inserted rows are in the virtual inserted table. So every row that existed BEFORE the trigger can be found by selecting all rows that are NOT IN the inserted table. And no - you cannot parameterize a trigger.

Comment: So what do you propose as a solution?

Comment: I propose that you THINK about the code and write it yourself. There are many hints in what I wrote. You learn nothing when given code. And beware that a trigger will fire even if NO rows are inserted. Again - THINK and learn.

Comment: I have  already posted my code , could you please see the question again ?

Comment: What do you do if someone inserts no rows or multiple rows?

Comment: The inserting of rows is executing when I called a stored procedure in a C# application

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If the "latest" row is always `TRUE`, then something like a `VIEW` would be much better at giving this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem ( the first question ) :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[dbo.TR_SetActive] ON [dbo].[test]
after INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS
BEGIN

update dbo.test set status=0  WHERE Id < (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM dbo.test)


END
```

For the second question , I have used to get the last record as parameter:

```
set @PersonId = (select PersonId from inserted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
 (
   id tinyint identity(1,1)not null primary key,
   person_id char(3)not null,
   name varchar(50)not null,
   status varchar(5) not null
)
insert dbo.Test(person_id,name,status)
 values('001','alex','false'),('002','mark','true');
go

SELECT *FROM DBO.Test

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dbo.II_Test;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.II_Test
ON dbo.Test  
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE DBO.Test SET status='FALSE';
  INSERT DBO.Test(person_id,name,status)
  SELECT I.person_id,I.name,I.status
   FROM inserted AS I
END
GO
insert dbo.Test(person_id,name,status)
   values('003','JANE','true');

select * from dbo.Test
```

Could you please check if the above is suitable for you

> > How can I update the rows that are existed before the insert using Trigger ( SQL Server )

For example, you can use INSTEAD OF-trigger

> > How can I pass a parameter to a trigger? (as an example PersonID)

This is not supported at all. If you need parameters the better way, I guess, is to use stored procedure

Comment: Sorry , I forget to mentioned that I would like to use the Trigger with a stored procedure not a simple SQL Query , could you please edit you answer? ( if the case is not be the same )

Comment: Sorry, seems we understand the situation a little bit different. Trigger is fired automatically  when certain action occurs (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE). Stored procedure is called by you. So. I guess, it would be better if you describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to fire the trigger after an insert or update ( so the calling of the stored procedure will be done in the C# application )

Comment: trigger will be fired automatically. You do not need do it by yourself. The only question here is to clarify what kind of trigger you need: AFTER or INSTEAD OF

Comment: If the `INSTEAD OF` is same as `BEFORE` ( that is not existed in SQL Server ) , I need `INSTEAD OF`

Comment: After testing your solution , I got this error : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'test' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Amended. ID now is an IDENTITY-column

Comment: Yes is an IDENTITY-column

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplfy with :

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.E_I_Test
ON dbo.Test  
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE T
  SET    status = CASE WHEN I.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM   dbo.Test as T
         LEFT OUTER JOIN inserted AS I 
            ON T.id = I.id;
```

BEWARE.... status is a reserved Transact SQL keyword. Should not be use for any SQL identifier (table, name, column neme...)

Corrections made...

Comment: ¨The status column has boolean type ( bit in SQL ) not nvarchar ,

Comment: I got an error , `Incorrect syntax near 'FALSE' `, you missed the `THEN` before `IS NULL`